# Trying to write an excel using a python code

Tags: python, excel, csv, web, web-scraping

I am making a  web scraping program that writes the job information of indeed & Stack overflow to Excel,
I am getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 7, in <module>
jobs = indeed_jobs + so_jobs
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "dict") to list
```

stackoverflow file is working.
but indeed  file stopped in the middle of code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOnPi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Vm3d.png)

Comment: hi, it seems that ```so_jobs``` is a dictionary, I don't know the structure of the dictionary but you could try doing this: ```jobs = indeed_jobs + list( so_jobs.values())```

Comment: Hi, as @EnriqueBet said so_jobs is a dictionary so you can declare `jobs = []` and do `jobs.append(indeed_jobs) jobs.append(so_jobs)`